# Build error: package android.app doesn't exist - build thinks android SDK isn't installed? (Android studio 1.0)

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I'm getting 100+ error when compiling this project.
I got SDK installed from version android 4.0 until 5.0

this is how it looked like in code, all the red letters are the libraries that AS1.0 doesn't recognize:
[image: SDK error]

and here's the gradle build message, there's a total of 101 errors:

[image: gradle build error]

and Here's the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.turbomanage.basic-http-client:http-client-android:0.89'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.lang:2.6'
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.8'
    compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
}
```

The question would be, If I've already installed the SDKs and includes everything in depedencies, how come gradle still think it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the basic function (like R) also have problem. You check your `build.gradle` with this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hellomap"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
}
```

Make sure the `buildToolsVersion` is the latest, also update your AS to 1.01

Comment: Hi, the compileSdkver was set to this: {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

Comment: AS is 1.0.1 and buildtools should be the latest too. but the problem occurs nevertheless

Comment: i run other project / made new project and compiles just fine. it seems like only this project is having problem, but I can't find out why.

Comment: Which project? Is it on github?